# Cannot use sqlite in electron with next.js project

Tags: node.js, sqlite, next.js, electron

I use next.js with electron template created my electron application,

```
./
├── README.md
├── electron-src
│   ├── db/proj.sqlite.db
│   ├── electron-next.d.ts
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── preload.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── main
│   ├── db
│   ├── index.js
│   └── preload.js
...
```

in this demo, I can not use the `db/proj.sqlite.db` file,

```
// electron-src/index.ts

const db = require('better-sqlite3')('./db/proj.sqlite.db', {});
console.log('db: ', db)
```

it will get error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot open database because the directory does not exist
at new Database (/Users/dele/dele/projects/test/vscode-layout-demo-01/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmmirror.com+better-sqlite3@8.6.0/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:65:9)
at Database (/Users/dele/dele/projects/test/vscode-layout-demo-01/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmmirror.com+better-sqlite3@8.6.0/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:11:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dele/dele/projects/test/vscode-layout-demo-01/main/ipc/test/db.test.handlers.js:6:37)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1269:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1324:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
```

the full code as below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fqn5zc

how to use sqlite in the prject?